# Need to intercept click on page but not specific a tag with id

Tags: jquery

I need to intercept click on every element in page (`a`, `img`, `link`, etc) but NOT a specific `a` tag with specific id (`go-privacy`).

In detail this is my code, but `:not` jQuery doesn't match.

```
$('html').on('click', '*:not( #go-privacy )', function() {
    // stuff 
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
$('body *:not(#go-privacy)').on('click', function() {    
    alert('click');
});
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/0xc5o0en/)

Answer (score 1):

In this case it would be better to attach a single delegated event to the `document` and filter out the element clicked by the `event.target.id`. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {    
    if (e.target.id == 'go-privacy')
        return;

    e.stopPropagation();    
    alert('click');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2oh0k7p8/)

The `stopPropagation()` call is to stop the event being raised multiple times as it bubbles up every element in the DOM tree.